# ¿Cómo enlazar datos al modelo de un dropdownlist llenado desde jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

necesito pasar el valor seleccionado de un dropdownlist al controlador a través de un modelo. Esta dropdownlist la lleno desde un jquery con datos contenidos en un fichero json.

El escenario es algo así:

Por un lado tengo una clase que me hace de ViewModel para pasar datos del controlador a la vista y viceversa.

```
 //Clase ViewModel
 public class MiClaseViewModel
 {
    public string ValorDropdownList {get; set; }
 }
```

Por otro lado tenemos la vista que sería algo así:

```
 //La vista   
 @model myApp.ViewModel.MiClaseViewModel
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
 {
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
       <label class="form-label">Descripción del campo</label>
       <select class="custom-select" id="ddl-ValorDropdownList"></select>
    </div>
 }
```

El archivo de datos json tiene este aspecto:

```
 //Archivo json
 [{"Codigo": "codigo_1", "Texto": "Texto codigo 1"},
 {"Codigo": "codigo_2", "Texto": "Texto codigo 2"}]
```

Y finalmente, enlazo un fichero de script a la vista y el código que llena el dropdownlist es este:

```
 //Codigo jquery
 let miDDL = $('#ddl-ValorDropdownList');
 miDDL.empty();

 miDDL.append('<option selected="true" disabled>Seleccionar un valor</option>');
 miDDL.prop('selectedIndex', 0);

 let urlDatosJson = '/Json/datos.json';
 $.getJSON(urlDatosJson, function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (key, entry) {
       miDDL.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', entry.Codigo).text(entry.Texto));
    });
 });
```

¿Es posible hacer esto?, ¿Cómo?

Comment: en el `name` del `select`  ponle ValorDropdownList y ya con eso tendrias que recibir el valor seleccionado en el controlador

Comment: Funciona perfectamente. Gracias

Comment: El comentario de @Xique es la respuesta.

Comment: ya coloque la respectiva respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el `name` del `select`ponle `ValorDropdownList` y ya con eso tendrías que recibir el valor seleccionado en el controlador así:

```
     @model myApp.ViewModel.MiClaseViewModel
     @using (Html.BeginForm())
     {
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
           <label class="form-label">Descripción del campo</label>
           <select class="custom-select" name="ValorDropdownList" id="ddl-ValorDropdownList"></select>
        </div>
     }
```